# US B1 Visa - dealing with changes in data submitted in DS-160

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

I'm applying for a US visa from India as an Indian citizen. The current wait time for an interview appointment is around 600 days (over 1.5 years).

I'm fine with this as I don't have immediate plans to travel. My concern, however, is that what if the details I submitted in the DS-160 form change between the time I filled the form and the actual interview date? Considering the large wait time, I think some details, for example, my residential address, travel history, etc might change. How do we handle these changes?

Comment: Wow, 600 days is more than an year and half.

Comment: Thanks @AnishSheela for calculating that! 